# Corebluetooth glitch on iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have been working extensively testing out the BLE capabilities of the iPhone 4s as well as the iPhone 5.

At the moment, all I have been accomplishing is pulling in the advertisement data from multiple TI BLE keyfobs and populating a `UITableView` with the `kCBAdvDataLocalName`, `ManufacturingData`, and `ServiceUUIDs` for each respective device.

Basically, as I pull in the advertisement data, I am also pulling in the peripheral's `UUID` and using this to populate the `datasource` array for the `tableview`. (i.e. if a new `UUID` is found and it is not in the `datasource` array, add it to the array and use that to retrieve the respective peripheral).

With the iPhone 5 this works flawlessly. However, when I test with an iPhone 4S (and I have tested with multiple) the `BLE` hardware pulls in NULL `UUIDs` therefore preventing me from adding any peripheral's info to the `datasource` array. In my console log, the phone does indeed discover each peripheral, and displays its `localname`, and manufacturing data, but every single device has a null `UUID`.

I have also ran my testing app on a 4S and a 5 simultaneously with the exact same code, and it will work on the 5 and not the 4S. So I was wondering if anyone has been having this same issue, whether it was a bug in the SDK or the hardware, or if there is a known workaround? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think that it doesn't give every info in the first discovery... I noticed, that on my iPhone 4S at least, that sometimes the Adv Data is nil... So before adding it to my Array of discovered devices, I check if it has a name, a UUID, and each advertisement data... And if not, I don't add it, but it will pass again in the didDiscoverPeripheral, with this time data added (updated) to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in iOS 6 is that the UUID's are not generated until you've actually connected to the device. UUID's are generated on the iOS side for each peripheral, so that's why you'll typically see a different UUID for the same peripheral when using different iOS devices. I usually check the UUID, and then if it is NULL, I will go off of the name. If the name is NULL however, then I do not populate it in the device list. Your other option is to quickly connect and then disconnect from the device. A big time hack, but it will generate the UUID and then be non-null from then on. Supposedly this problem will be fixed in the next version of iOS.

Comment: I can confirm in iOS7 the `peripheral.identifier` is fill in with a unique id (`NSUUID`) before ever being connected.